# QTableWIdget получить координаты ячейки с фокуса

Tags: c++, qt, события, qtablewidget, focus

При первом нажатии на ячейку функция возвращает -1, а уже при втором нажатии возвращает корректный адрес.

Как сделать так, чтобы результат возвращался сразу при нажатии на выделенную ячейку без лишнего щелчка?

```cpp
void InventoryTable::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {

    if(event->button() == Qt::RightButton){

        this->currentRow(); // при первом нажатии возвращает -1   
    }
    QTableWidget::mousePressEvent(event) ;
}
```

Comment: Вот этот вызов `QTableWidget::mousePressEvent(event) ;` делать в первую очередь, а потом уже все остальное

Comment: Шикарно .Спасибо большое!